# Error running makeglossaries in TexStudio on Mac

Tags: glossaries, texstudio

I have been using TexStudio v2.12.16 on Mac OS X, using texlive 2019. I have a document I'm writing that includes a list of acronyms, using the glossaries package. When I press F9 to run `makeglossaries`, I get the following error:

```
Process started: makeglossaries "researchquestion"

env: perl: No such file or directory

Process exited with error(s)
```

I've checked that perl is installed and working:

```
/usr/bin/env perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

When I try `makeglossaries` from the command line, it works fine. How do I get it to work from within TexStudio?

Comment: Is Perl along the path TeXStudio passes to the process?

Comment: @HerbSchulz perl is in /usr/bin. I don't know what exactly TexStudio passes in to `makeglossaries`, which is a perl script.